# DialogFragment onCreateDialog()

Tags: android

My app crashes when I add the onCreateDialog Method to the DialogFragment class. If I don't add that method, it shows the dialog which has a list. I went through other similar topics but it din't solve my problem. Please, I could use some assistance here. Here's my code.

```
public class SubVitalsEntryDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    ArrayList<SubVitals> subVitalList = new ArrayList<SubVitals>();
    ListView mylist;

    public static SubVitalsEntryDialogFragment newInstance(ArrayList<SubVitals> sub) {
        SubVitalsEntryDialogFragment f = new SubVitalsEntryDialogFragment();

        // Supply num input as an argument.
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putParcelableArrayList("subVitalList", sub);
        f.setArguments(args);
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.subvitals_dialog_layout, null, false);
        mylist = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.vitalEntryListView);
        getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        subVitalList = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("subVitalList");
        ArrayAdapter<SubVitals> adapter = new MyListAdapter(subVitalList);
        mylist.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = null;
        alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        //View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.subvitals_dialog_layout, null);
        //alertDialogBuilder.setView(view);
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Enter your vital");
        alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        return alertDialogBuilder.create();

    }

    private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SubVitals>{

        public MyListAdapter(ArrayList<SubVitals> subVitalList){

            super(getActivity(), R.layout.subvitals_dialog_layout, subVitalList);
            Log.d("Tag", "super okay");
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            //return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            //Making sure we've a view to work with(may have been given null
            Log.d("TAG","Inside get view");
            View itemView = convertView;
            if (itemView == null)
                itemView = LayoutInflater.from(this.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.sub_vital_template, parent, false);

            String currentVital = subVitalList.get(position).getSubVitalName();

            //Fill the view

            TextView vitalText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById((R.id.vitalEntryListView));
            vitalText.setText(currentVital);

            return itemView;
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return subVitalList.size();
        }
    }

}
```

Logcat:

```
04-08 21:48:28.032    2489-2489/com.cinch.getvitalsapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.cinch.getvitalsapp, PID: 2489
    android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:301)
            at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:231)
            at android.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:356)
            at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:373)
            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:274)
            at android.app.DialogFragment.onStart(DialogFragment.java:490)
            at android.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:2077)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:922)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:833)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1452)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:447)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

____________EDIT__________________

```
public class SubVitalsEntryDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    ArrayList<SubVitals> subVitalList = new ArrayList<SubVitals>();
    ListView mylist;

    public static SubVitalsEntryDialogFragment newInstance(ArrayList<SubVitals> sub) {
        SubVitalsEntryDialogFragment f = new SubVitalsEntryDialogFragment();

        // Supply num input as an argument.
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putParcelableArrayList("subVitalList", sub);
        f.setArguments(args);
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(final View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){

        getDialog().requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.subvitals_dialog_layout, null, false);
        mylist = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.vitalEntryListView);
        //getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        //getDialog().requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        subVitalList = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("subVitalList");
        ArrayAdapter<SubVitals> adapter = new MyListAdapter(subVitalList);
        mylist.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = null;
        alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        //View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.subvitals_dialog_layout, null);
        //alertDialogBuilder.setView(view);
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Enter your vital");
        alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        return alertDialogBuilder.create();

    }

    private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SubVitals>{

        public MyListAdapter(ArrayList<SubVitals> subVitalList){

            super(getActivity(), R.layout.subvitals_dialog_layout, subVitalList);
            Log.d("Tag", "super okay");
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            //return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            //Making sure we've a view to work with(may have been given null
            Log.d("TAG","Inside get view");
            View itemView = convertView;
            if (itemView == null)
                itemView = LayoutInflater.from(this.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.sub_vital_template, parent, false);

            String currentVital = subVitalList.get(position).getSubVitalName();

            //Fill the view

            TextView vitalText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById((R.id.vitalEntryListView));
            vitalText.setText(currentVital);

            return itemView;
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return subVitalList.size();
        }
    }

}


04-08 21:48:28.032    2489-2489/com.cinch.getvitalsapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.cinch.getvitalsapp, PID: 2489
    android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:301)
            at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:231)
            at android.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:356)
            at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:373)
            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:274)
            at android.app.DialogFragment.onStart(DialogFragment.java:490)
            at android.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:2077)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:922)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:833)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1452)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:447)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
04-08 21:48:34.235    2489-2489/com.cinch.getvitalsapp I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 2489 SIG: 9
04-08 21:48:34.511    2517-2532/com.cinch.getvitalsapp D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
04-08 21:48:34.523    2517-2517/com.cinch.getvitalsapp D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa6c56580, tid 2517
04-08 21:48:34.565    2517-2517/com.cinch.getvitalsapp D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
04-08 21:48:34.599    2517-2529/com.cinch.getvitalsapp I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3210(243KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 16% free, 952KB/1135KB, paused 39.970ms total 95.451ms
04-08 21:48:34.629    2517-2532/com.cinch.getvitalsapp D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa6c56860, tid 2532
04-08 21:48:34.644    2517-2532/com.cinch.getvitalsapp I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-08 21:48:34.674    2517-2532/com.cinch.getvitalsapp D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
04-08 21:48:34.692    2517-2532/com.cinch.getvitalsapp W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-08 21:48:34.692    2517-2532/com.cinch.getvitalsapp W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xae0ea540, error=EGL_SUCCESS
04-08 21:48:35.009    2517-2517/com.cinch.getvitalsapp W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
```

Comment: Can you call getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); before inflating your view

Comment: tried that, still same result

Comment: @HeisenBerg: where have you reached with this ?

Comment: sorry that I forgot to mark your answer as correct.

Comment: I did already. thanks for the help. cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

with

```
getDialog().requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

and do this in `onViewCreated()`, not `onCreateView()`:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(final View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){      
    getDialog().requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
}
```

Comment: it says "Can't resolve method requestFeature(int)". also DialogFragment does not have a class named onViewCreated()

Comment: so, onCreateView not needed?

Comment: `onCreateView()` is definitely needed, but only inflate the view in `onCreateView()`. call `requestWindowFeature` in `onViewCreated()` as I have shown in answer

Comment: post your latest code in the question and also give the logcat error

Comment: do one thing ... uninstall the app completely from your phone and then re-install it from your IDE and then test it

Comment: I don't think you can still be getting a `requestFeature() must be called before adding content` error because now you are not using `requestFeature()`.

Comment: I tried, still not working, app crashes. Content i.e ListView is set on the onActivityCreated() method. does that run before onViewCreated and onCreateView?